# Overwrite the data in excel using SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have to load data from Sql server to excel daily and have to send that excel via mail. If I run two time the same package , data will be appended into the excel. I dont want to append the data, but want to overwrite If same day. And If run next day It should create a new file with Filename and suffixed by Date like Filename_20160301 for 1st march. How do we achieve this? Could you give by example as i am new to SSIS?

I do not want to use drop and create excel table as I have some limitation. i want to achieve this using script task.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

- For the Filename_date, create a user variable and in the first step use a SQL Task with a Query to get date or use the System::StartTime in your expression

`SELECT Max(Month) as MonthMax FROM yourtable;`

- To overwrite the file, i don't how to do, but you can use a C# script for delete or move the file in other folder. Move it in a '20160301'folder if the variable is the same for exemple. Just be careful if there are files with the same name.